# Domain Creation - Any Difference?

Tags: domains

Is there any difference when creating domain hosting `.com` in Europe or America? Can it still be reached by both continents at the same weight?

Comment: What do you mean by weight? Did you not see the UK series The IT crowd?? The [internet doesn't weigh anything](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DiDbyYGrswtg&ei=cXniUuakFcOw7AbL7IGwAw&usg=AFQjCNFBy44NoDrPLOCiq1g54j1FoZ9dgw&bvm=bv.59930103,d.ZGU)!!

Answer (score 1):

Domain names are just a mapping of a name and IP-address. Computers do not understand names (per se) but find numbers very easy to munch and process on.

As such what is your domain has no impact on where it can be accessed (though I would advise a bit against `.cn` domains).

The factors that affect how FAST your page open are another story.

In order for a domain name to be accessible it needs as a minimum 2 DNS servers which are used to tell the world the mapping of name->IP. As such how fast they respond is a factor how speedy your site is.

If you can afford it use route53 (or similar) to host your DNS. This way you get quite a stable and spread everywhere dns infrastructure.

Pick a good host to put your files and follow the Yahoo/Google guidelines on making speedy pages and you should be set.

Comment: Thanks for extensive reply. The main thing I am solving how the page can be discovered by Europe and American users. If the domain is hosted in Europe, if it can still be easily searched in America or not (using Google and so on). And yeah, also the quickness of page loading plays a role.

Comment: Yes it can of course be discovered. Google/bing are prety quick on finding new sites as they are being set-up so no worries. For speed/accessibility main concern is the hosting. Try to pick a big one like 1and1, rackspace, bluehost, etc. Lightness of the pages can be achieved in different ways and this highly depends on the content and the skill of the dev.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make much difference. If you want a site which is likely to be accessed around the world I would suggest `.com` as the `.co.uk` is a local (UK) domain. If this isn't going to be the case go with whichever one you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. More info to be found in comment for zeridon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a question about SEO as well as if it is accessible.

Each domain name is actually a human readable version of the IP address. If you ping www.google.com you will see the IP address of where it lives.

All IP's are, typically accessible from any continent providing the ISP doesn't block them.

In regards to the weight, I assume you're talking about SEO. If you have a site which is only national, then use the relevant code, such as .co.uk or .es. They can still be found from other places, but *may* not do so well in Google (depending on the search phrase, language on the site and language used to make the search). If you are a global entity, then it is normal to use .com or similar (.net). Some times, it makes sense to have local sites and 1 national site, but each website and business structure/need is unique.

You then mention in a comment `"...If the domain is hosted in Europe, if it can still be easily searched in America "`
First off, lets' make it clear, owning a .fr domain doesn't mean it must be hosted in France. It can be hosted any where. In regards to where you host it and it's impact on Google, this is tricky. IMO it doesn't make a difference, or if it does, it's minimal. The reason it can make a difference is (IMO) based upon how quickly the site loads. An average server speed (machine/lines etc) will typically respond faster in your browser if it's closer than one that is very far away. Having slow/unresponsive websites can result in worse rankings.

Comment: If you talk about hosting globally you may want to add an aditional section about involving a CDN to host static content